# Relative Repo Path in __init__.py?

Tags: python, repository, organization

I'll share a problem that we are kinda having at work.  We have a code repo and there are files spread all around (currently trying to get everyone to clean up).  The issue is that with every file that gets created we are having to make a `RELATIVE_REPO_PATH` (RRP) in order to import other files in our repo.  The repo is hosted using mercurial, and all users have a clone of the repo on their local machines.  They each have the ability to push and pull updates as needed.  This means that the RRP cannot be hardcoded in anywhere.  Below I'll show an example of our structure, and also show what we currently do to get a RRP.

An example of our structure.

```
    .
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── misc_functions
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── myTest.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    └── Test
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── pythonfile1 (copy).py
        └── pythonfile1.py
```

Here is what we currently do at work

```
import os
import sys
if not hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    RELATIVE_REPO_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.path.append(RELATIVE_REPO_PATH)
        sys.path.pop(0)
else:
    RELATIVE_REPO_PATH = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

As you can see, however deep you are from the root of the repo, you need to add more or less os.path.dirname.  We have tried this with while loops, however, alot of our files import each other and it's a kind of mess.

Is there any way to just add a simple snippet of code to the top level **init**.py or all the **init**.py files that would eliminate the constant copy and pasting of this code?

Just to clarify, everything that we do works just fine.  Want to know if there is a way to set up a global RRP in the init.py that will work anywhere there is an init.py.

Comment: so if you are in mytest.py you are having trouble doing from Test import pythonfile? Not sure I am understanding your issue.

Comment: So yeah, say that I'm in pythonfile1.py and I need to import something from myTest.py  Currently we do the RELATIVE_REPO_PATH in the main of the file.  Everything works just fine, but I was wondering if we can add some code in the __init__.py files so that we can just have a global RELATIVE_REPO_PATH set up, so we don't have to copy and paste that same code into all of our files.